# Prove or disprove that $g^*: H^2(S^2; \mathbb{Z}) \to H^2(T^2; \mathbb{Z})$ is trivial for any map $g: T^2 \to S^2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology

I am trying to show that $g^*$ is non-trivial, but I am having a hard time justifying it based on this commutative diagram. Is $g^*$ just an isomorphism? Here is a screenshot of my work. I'd appreciate any feedback.

[image]

Comment: Here is a related post: [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/38843/induced-map-in-cohomology-in-a-map-from-torus-to-sphere)

Comment: The conclusion at the end is not right: even if $h$ is an isomorphism, $g_*$ could be trivial, and hence $g^*$ would be trivial too. For example, $g$ could be a constant map. Perhaps what you want to say is that *if* $g_*$ is not trivial then $g^*$ is not either.

Comment: Ah, yes. That rings true. Thank you, Pedro!

Comment: If $g$ is the constant map, then $g^*$ is trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of $T^2$ as a square with opposite sides identified. Then the map $g: T^2\to S^2$ induced by collapsing the four sides of the square to a single point induces an isomorphism $g^*: H^2(S^2, \mathbb{Z})\to H^2(T^2, \mathbb{Z})$.